# Maven Compilation Error without any errors from the compiler

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java application built with Maven. Our CI system (Bamboo) is configured to use Maven 3.1.1, and I use Maven 3.5 locally. We're using Java 8u152 everywhere; I can also reproduce the problem using 8u144.

Today, after I committed a trivial change to the Java code, we started getting this error (paths and project names obfuscated):

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project-name ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to /bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/ASP-CAS-CJT/project/service/target/test-classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.036s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 13 15:15:51 EST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/715M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project project-name: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Other similarly-built services build fine. This build passes when I run it locally. It also builds fine on the Bamboo host using Maven 3.5.0 manually from the command line. Invoking Maven with `-e` or `-X` gives no additional useful information; the stacktrace just indicates that there was a compilation failure.

Furthermore, the target/test-classes directory exists and contains all 35 expected .class files; it appears that compilation was every bit as successful as I expected it to be.

I've scoured the POM and parent POMs looking for hooks related to the test compile phase. I found nothing, and the output above indicates that there are none.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing Maven to think there's a compiler error when there is none. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Without knowing the code, it's quite hard to tell. I'd suggest the following: 1) post also the log with -e (at least to show what's being passed to the compiler) 2) find which is the test class causing the build failure (like: remove half of the classes, compile, if failing remove another half, etc.); then, when you have the class, post it here (obfuscated) or start narrowing the code to see which line is failing and then post the line 3) check which JDK (Open? Oracle? IBM? etc.) is being used locally and on Bamboo 4) more to come based on the additional inputs from previous points

Comment: I'm less interested in finding the compile error than in finding why Maven is not showing the compile error.

That said, I'll see what I can gather. For starters: Oracle JDKs everywhere.

Comment: Found the problem. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short version: javac was encountering a StackOverflowError (irony noted!  ), caused by a 693-deep chained method call on a Builder.

To diagnose: we used Maven's `-X` output to extract the actual command to javac, then executed that separately. This gave us javac's full output, which does not appear to be available using Maven. The output told us which class it was working on and then spat out the stacktrace for the SOE. I then looked at the history of commits to that file and found that, coincident with the trivial change I committed, someone else had added a few calls to the builder chain.

To verify the diagnosis, we added `-J-Xss256M` to javac's args and ran it again; compilation succeeded. Rather than run the compiler with nonstandard args (and spending the time figuring out how to get Maven to invoke it that way), I then split the builder chain into two smaller chains. With that change committed, the build is now passing in Bamboo.

Note: in the question, I said that the compiler output contained all 35 expected class files; this was a coincidence. It contained 35 files, which matched up with the number of source files, but thanks to some inner classes, the 35 .java files should have generated 42 .class files.

We're using an old version of maven-compiler-plugin (v3.1, from 2013). I'm going to experiment with whether a newer version does a better job of exposing the failure.

Comment: Excellent - let us know about those additional experiment. Then, if my below answer helped exposing the actual failure (which was the topic here) please upvote/elect. Hope that helped!

Comment: First yes upgrade to newer version of maven-compiler-plugin and if you find an issue please report it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER

Comment: I reported MCOMPILER-325, and then later discovered that the issue had already been reported as MCOMPILER-308.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the error of the creator had a different error cause. But since my issue let me here and I had a different cause: Check if you fork the compiler plugin somewhere:

E.g. like this:

`<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
    <maxmem>2048m</maxmem>
    <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
    <source>${java.version}</source>
    <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`

In this case the outcome can be ugly. It works on some machines where JAVA_HOME is set generally correct and will not where you just set it in a local window. And the error is not helpful at all as the forked compiler will not return helpful info.

Comment: Yes, it only happens if you fork the compiler. I apologize for not making that clear in my answer. Will edit. (Note, however, that for large projects, _not_ forking the compiler is often not an option.)

Comment: For me this didn't work. It caused error: `Fatal error compiling: error: invalid flag: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. 
But after removing the related part `<compilerArgs><arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</arg></compilerArgs>`
it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, however the cause is different. In my case, the parent pom.xml included a path to a compiler:

```
<executable>/opt/java8/bin/javac</executable>
```

that is not present on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing memory in configuration of maven-compiler-plugin helped! This is a relevant fragment of `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>${java.version}</release>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
        <maxmem>2048m</maxmem>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After this maven presented the root cause of my problem (some check style plugin error) and I could solve it. In my case `java.version = 11`.

Answer (score -1):

Maven 3.1.1 is quite old and JDK8 was not yet around when it's been released, thus it might be unable to properly handle your Java 8 project. Same story for the maven-compiler-plugin. Check [Maven Release History](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) and [maven-compiler-plugin releases](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) and [Java release dates](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_dates.xml) for more cross-referencing.

So, either (ordered by chance of success):

1. change to any Maven 3.x > 3.1.x
2. change maven-compiler-plugin's version to 3.7.0 via `<pluginManagement>`
3. narrow down code to spot what compilation error is not properly managed

Comment: As noted in the question, Maven 3.5.0 exhibits the same problem. maven-compiler-plugin 3.7.0 with verbose=true outputs the names of the source files as it compiles each one, but does not report the StackOverflowError.